# Needs constructor/destructor/type conversion error

Tags: c++, class, constructor, type-conversion, destructor

I get the error that after `fracMult` and before the `(` `I'm missing a constructor, destructor, or type conversion`. I don't know what it means by that.

```
#include <cstdlib>  
#include <iostream>  
#include <cmath>  
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

class fraction
{
private:
    int numerator;
    int denom;
    bool positive;
public:
fraction();
    fraction(int numerator, int denom, bool positive);
    void inputFrac();
    void printFrac();
    fraction fracMult(fraction b);
    fraction fracDiv(fraction b);
    fraction fracAdd(fraction b);
    fraction fracSub(fraction b);
};

fraction f1, f2, fresult;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

f1.inputFrac();
f2.inputFrac();

cout << "The result of a * b is: ";
fresult = f1.fracMult(f2);
fresult.printFrac();

    return 0;
}

void fraction::printFrac()
{
    if(!positive){
        cout << "-";
    }
cout << numerator << "/" << denom << endl;
}

void fraction::inputFrac()
{
    string tempchar;

    cout << "What is the numerator? ";
    cin >> numerator;
    cout << "What is the denominator? ";
    cin >> denom;
    cout << "Is the fraction positive? (Y or N): ";
    cin >> tempchar;

    while(tempchar != "Y" && tempchar != "N"){
        cout << "Please enter Y or N: ";
        cin >> tempchar;
    }

    if(tempchar == "Y"){
        positive = true;
    }
    else{
        positive = false;
    }
}

fraction::fracMult(f2){ 
    fresult.numerator = f1.numerator * f2.numerator;
    fresult.denom = f1.denom * f2.denom;
    if(f1.positive != f2.positive){
        fresult.positive = false;
    }
    return fresult;
}

fraction::fracDiv(){
}

fraction::fracAdd(){
}

fraction::fracSub(){   
}
```

I know that fracDiv, fracAdd, and fracSub are all empty, I'm just working on making the fracMult work first.

I'm very new to c++, so sometimes small, obvious errors still evade me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the return type in the implementations of those functions. You are also missing the argument in the implementations.

```
fraction fraction::fracDiv(fraction b){
// ^^^^                    ^^^^^
}
```

Only constructor and destructor implementations can omit the return type.

```
// OK
fraction::fraction(){ ... }

// OK
fraction::~fraction(){ ... }
```

Comment: When I add the 'fraction' at the beginning of the line, it then tells me that  `main.cpp:81:10: error: prototype for 'fraction fraction::fracMult()' does not match any in class 'fraction'` and that `main.cpp:26:14: error: candidate is: fraction fraction::fracMult(fraction)` for each of the 4 separate Add, Sub, Div, and Mult

Comment: @EricBraunreiter, the arguments also have to be added. Updated my answer.

Comment: Okay that solved that problem, but now it seems as though it's not letting me initialize f1, f2, and fresult as fractions. Is there a certain way I have to initialize them since 'fraction' is a class, instead of just `fraction f1, f2, fresult;` like I did when fraction was a structure? (Sorry if these are dumb questions - like I said, I'm still pretty new.)

Comment: @EricBraunreiter, since the class defines constructors that are different than the default constructor, the default constructor is deleted by the compiler. You'll have to use the constructor you have defined to construct instances of the class.

Comment: I would recommend defining a default constructor, in which you can initialize the member variables to some sensible values: E.g. 0, 1, true.

Comment: So, do you mean up under public: to put `fraction(int numerator = 0, int denom = 1, bool positive = true);` Without that, the errors that I'm getting  are `undefined reference to 'fraction::fraction()'` and `relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol 'fraction::fraction()'` three different times.